# Hyperledger Fabric "fabric-ca-client" Error Code: 71 - Authorization failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, certificate-authority

I am trying to list identities of ca server using fabric-ca-client as below

> fabric-ca-client identity list --id *nameofidentityfromfabric-ca-server-config.yaml* -u https://username:password@localhost:8054 --tls.certfiles <path to /tls/ca.crt> --mspdir <path to /peer0.org2.example.com/msp>

But ca servers responds with Error as below

> Error: Response from server: Error Code: 71 - Authorization failure

Below is the code in **fabric-ca-server-config.yaml**

```
identities:
 - name: username
   pass: password
   type: client
   affiliation: ""
   attrs:
      hf.Registrar.Roles: "*"
      hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles: "*"
      hf.Revoker: true
      hf.IntermediateCA: true
      hf.GenCRL: true
      hf.Registrar.Attributes: "*"
      hf.AffiliationMgr: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I hadn't enrolled bootstrap identity yet.
Below code does that

```
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'adminusername', enrollmentSecret: 'adminpassword' });
        const x509Identity = {
        credentials: {
            certificate: enrollment.certificate,
            privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
          },
        mspId: 'Org2MSP',
        type: 'X.509',
        };
        await wallet.put('admin', x509Identity);
```

Once bootstrap identity is enrolled, create user object for that identity with below code

```
const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
const provider = wallet.getProviderRegistry().getProvider(adminIdentity.type);
const adminUser = await provider.getUserContext(adminIdentity, 'admin');
```

Now invoke newIdentityService() of FabricCAServices class as below to get list of identities.

```
const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
let connectionProfile = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('../gateway/connection-org2.yaml', 'utf8'));
// Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
const caInfo = connectionProfile.certificateAuthorities['ca.org2.example.com'];
const caTLSCACerts = caInfo.tlsCACerts.pem;
const ca = new FabricCAServices(caInfo.url, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, caInfo.caName);
let identityService = ca.newIdentityService();
let registeredidentities = await identityService.getAll(adminUser);
console.dir(registeredidentities, { depth: null })
```

Answer (score 0):

fabric-ca doesn't use password authentication (which is what you are trying to do), it uses token authentication created from an enrolled identity via it's certificate and private key. You need to first enroll your bootstrap identity which looks to be `username` in your above example, then use that enrolled identity to perform fabric-ca registrar tasks.

This section in the docs provides some more detail https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#enrolling-the-bootstrap-identity about enrolling then goes on to show examples of performing other taks once you have enrolled the bootstrap identity